# Rigify Fingers shrunk inside themselves

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, rigify, pose-mode

The fingers went inside themselves for no reason, i can drag the finger detail bones and get them to how they were before, but i cant scale to close them anymore

[image]

i've also noticed that whenever i reset the pose with alt+g after i fix them they shrink back, how can i fix this?? I've been animating the project for a while so i think ive only transfered animation data and reset the pose a couple of times

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because you created the bones, and scale the root of each finger, but later placed the second falange manually.
Save an alternative file with a different name, we're going to do deep changes:

1. Enter edit mode on your METARIG, delete your hands and fingers.
2. go back to OBJECT mode.
3. Create another meta rig (shift+A>Armature>human metarig). Delete everything except the left hand. Exit back to OBJECT MODE
4. Select your original metarig, enter EDIT MODE. Delete both hands and fingers.
   Exit back to OBJECT MODE.
5. Select your single left metarig hand, then shift click select the original metarig. Press CTRL+J
6. Make sure your bone layers have everything placed on square 1.
7. Enter edit mode, Parent the hand to the forearm.L
8. Select the left hand metarig, Right click>Symmetrize (this will create the right hand parented already to the right arm)
9. while in EDIT mode, switch your axis orientation from GLOBAL (or LOCAL) to NORMAL, and in the selection method use "ACTIVE element". This is crucial for you to click, select a bone and rotate it/move it regarding its own axis.
   **HEre's the crucial point**
   USE THE LASSO TOOL (ctrl+RMB) to encircle both the root of the finger and the joint connection. Help your self orientating the camera view with 1,3 on the numpad (front and side view), then go to perspective and final align the finger. As long as you DON'T separate your joints, your finger will generate in the correct proportion to the hand.
10. Finish and save this file. Enter OBJECT MODE, click on the running man icon, and press GENERATE.
11. Now you can scale (to flex fingers), move and rotate (to orient fingers individually) from the long pole controls.
    [image]